# Does GPA matter ?!

Tags: masters, undergraduate, europe, gpa, abroad

I'm still undergraduate, have 2 years to graduate but i don't like my major so much and my college. i go twice a week. i don't attend lectures too much because professors and the contents are so weak and doesn't based on understanding just on  final exams and i don't like it. i started to learn from Youtube and other websites but the GPA is not good is about 2.3 so my wish and hope is to do master abroad as Europe (Sweden or other country) to live there and work better than middle east. 
So it can be or not ?! is it possible ?! 
i don't search for scholarship.. i can pay for studying but not much from working there but at least understand what i really study not just rules and put them in a paper to get full mark..

Comment: "my wish and hope is to do master abroad as Europe (Sweden or other country) to live there and work", work on what if you don't like your major ?

Comment: I like my major . i don't like the way they teach you it in my college and you are not allowed to go to another one.

Comment: yeah start it over and waste 3 years ... i can't it's 3 years .... rules here are very difficult as i now study mechanical engineering if i want to go to another one i will study another major....... i don't want it because i like mechanical things i want to work in this field. it's complicated. my hope is 2 years again and in 2019 apply in master abroad so it could be with my 2.3-2.6 GPA ?!

Comment: I'd really try to get the GPA up. You must go to class even if you don't like it!

Comment: studies here are not credit hours so what you study is done .... it's now 2.3 i will work hard this next two years to get 2.6-2.7 maximum (fixed) so what you think ?! i'm good in software programs and other things, i can get recommendation letters too so ?

Comment: No sure ... i pay to study and understand if i won't why i will continue !

Comment: I am voting to close this question as it is related to undergrad course.

Comment: @chessofnerd Who says that ?

Comment: You can find professors in your department which you like their style, and study the courses by yourself from books, and ask your question to those professor. I also do this actually, but in my case, I generally study further concepts by myself.

Comment: You also want to build positive relationships with your professors. You'll need their recommendations when you apply to graduate school.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer:**

Yes, it does matter.

**Slightly longer answer:**

The GPA is one of the few ways universities can use to assess someone's academic abilities. There are a lot of flaws with the system but there aren't many alternatives. Presenting the courses and grades automatically indicates your (alleged) proficiency in the material. If you think your classes suck and you learn better outside of class, you should be doing the work in addition to your schoolwork - not instead.

In addition, the ability to keep your grades up is an important indicator of perseverance and of the ability to set and reach goals. Whatever profession you will end up having, you will inevitably have to do some things that you don't enjoy much. A successful person won't complain and throw in the towel if the task is boring - they'll suck it up and do it anyways. So your ability to go to boring classes is, in fact, an indicator of important personality skills that also contribute to your GPA.

It's sad if the educational system doesn't satisfy your needs, but you can still try to make the most of it and supplement it with your own education. That said, history knows plenty of successful college dropouts, so my advice is by no means universal. However, my suspicion is, a lot of people in the academia will think like me, so if you do want to get a Master's, it probably isn't a good idea to ignore the system altogether.